# Adding popovers to fullcalendar events in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, ng-bootstrap

Im using angular2-fullcalendar and ng-bootstrap library i want to implement popover from ng-bootstrap into fullcalendar events so far i have something like:

```
...
    eventRender: function(event, element){
              element.attr("ngbPopover",event.title);
              element.attr("triggers", "mouseenter:mouseleave");
              element.attr("popoverTitle","title");
          }
...
```

but this doesn't work, anyone have idea how to get this working ?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't an error message or even a problem description. Precisely what is your issue? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Im trying to do something like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/6vmjt9rb/ , my code doesnt throw any error or anything it just doesn't work, i dont know how to implement this in angular 2

Comment: ok well I don't know anything about Angular, sorry. I thought you had a problem with fullCalendar itself. Sorry I can't help you further.